# Updating multiple values SQL, checking on values in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am going through some unwanted behaviour in my code, and wonder if the order of which values are updated is important.

We have value x,y,z that are evaluated based on each other.
X is either 'I', 'U' or 'D'
Y is either 'J' or 'N'
Z is either 'J' or 'N'

which values that are valid is evaluated based on the other ones such as:

```
UPDATE values
SET X = CASE WHEN X IN ('I','U') AND (Y = 'N' OR Y IS NULL) THEN 'D'
             WHEN X = 'D' AND Y = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE X
END,
Y = CASE WHEN X IN ('I','U') AND (Y = 'N' OR Y IS NULL) THEN 'J'
         WHEN X = 'D' AND Y = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE Y
END,
Z = CASE WHEN X <> 'D' AND Z = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE Z
END
```

My question is, does the order of the cases affect the updates after, or not. 
Would the updated X value be evaluated in the following cases?

Comment: yes. It does. order of the `CASE` is important

Comment: I assume that is why my values are reverted then, thanks!

Comment: `WHEN Y = 'D' AND Y = 'J' THEN 'N'` I'm assuming it should be `WHEN X = 'D' AND Y = 'J' THEN 'N'`...

Comment: Yes, thank you Zohar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the order of the columns in the `SET` clause of an update is meaningless.
The entire row is updated at once in an update statement, meaning you are validating your updates using the *old* values in the columns.

Here's a quick demo:

Create and populate sample table:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    A int,
    B int
)

INSERT INTO @T (A, B) VALUES (1, 2)
```

Update `B` to the value of `A`, and `A` to `3`:

```
UPDATE @T 
SET B = A,
    A = 3

SELECT A, B 
FROM @T

-- Result:

A   B
3   1
```

Update `A` to `4`, and `B` to the value of `A`:

```
UPDATE @T 
SET A = 4,
    B = A

SELECT A, B 
FROM @T

-- Result:    

A   B
4   3
```

[See it live on rextester.](https://rextester.com/CKJ30958)

What you can do is use a stored procedure or a prepared statement, and set the values on the table according to the parameters values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateValues
(
    @X char(1), 
    @Y char(1), 
    @Z char(1)
)
AS

UPDATE [values]
SET X = CASE WHEN @X IN ('I','U') AND (@Y = 'N' OR @Y IS NULL) THEN 'D'
             WHEN @X = 'D' AND @Y = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE @X
END,
Y = CASE WHEN @X IN ('I','U') AND (@Y = 'N' OR @Y IS NULL) THEN 'J'
         WHEN @X = 'D' AND @Y = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE @Y
END,
Z = CASE WHEN @X <> 'D' AND @Z = 'J' THEN 'N'
ELSE @Z
END
```

This way, you will be setting the values on the table based on the new values and not on the old values.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! This is acctually a stored procedure created by my colleagues quite a few years ago, and I am trying to figure out why it updates stored values wrongly. I assume it is the logic of the when clauses since the order does not matter.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)